# Cloudflare prohibits API GET request

Tags: nginx, cloudflare, restrictions

I am having a trouble with my API's GET request. I settled cloudflare as a firewall for my web application. Behind it, my web application is working on Nginx server. All HTTP Requests are working for the application. But when I try to execute API service, I can execute only POST requests, but GET requests. The endpoint is like [www.myapp.com/api/sample-service](http://www.myapp.com/api/sample-service). I suspect cloudflare elects API's GET somehow but I could not find out any reason for it. What is wrong with API's GET requests?

Comment: Contact cloudflare support. Provide SPECIFICS - not "blabla" but specifics as with a network monitor.

Comment: Voting to close: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution. Problem is related with the Rocket Loader function of Cloudflare. It somehow disables all AJAX requests in JavaScripts. Disabling the Rocket Loader function fixed the problem!